# EF 4.1 DBContext - Apply filter loading related entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I'm using `EF 4.1 DBContext API`, and I'm trying to load a parent entity named `User` and then explicitly load related `Project` entities using a `.Where(x => x.IsEnabled)` filter:

I found a suggested approach [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) under "**Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities**". But I cannot figure out why `user.Projects` is not being populated. Using SQL Profiler, I have verified I'm querying `Projects` and returning the data. But it's not being loaded into my user object.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
    public User GetUser(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.UserName, userName, true) == 0);

                context.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.Projects).Query().Where(x => x.IsEnabled).Load();

                //TODO: I expect user.Projects.Count() > 0.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWrapper.DumpException(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 User.projects = context.projects.select(x => x.user).where(x => x.isenabled);
```

Comment: I'm asking how to filter the child Project objects. Not the User objects.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to get back a single user by user name, but only load projects that are enabled. i.e. user.Projects.All(x => x.IsEnabled) == true

Comment: Is Projects a table in the database that has a foreign key to users?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23810/discussion-between-robert-and-john-russell)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem recently, this is what I did. Hope you find it useful.

```
var query = context.User.Where(x => x.UserName == userName)
            .Include(x => x.Projects.All(p => p.IsEnabled == true))

var data = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm curious what version of EF you are using. I'm using EF 4.1 and DbContext API... My .Include method only takes strings and not lambdas. Any ideas?

Comment: Same 4.1 include this in your code: using System.Data.Entity; and you should be fine. It has the overload for the lambda expression.